# Port 8005 Required by Tomcat, already in use

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, port

I am attempting to refresh my knowledge of Java. I've downloaded and started using Eclipse Mars. I was following a tutorial that uses Tomcat. I tried to create and start a server. I received the following message in the image: [Port 8005 is in use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YbaS.jpg).

I checked and surely it is but I don't know what is using it or how to either stop that process or make Tomcat use another port. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: "What's listening on a TCP socket on my computer" or "how do I configure this web server" aren't really programming questions, and if it's for personal use they're probably a better fit on superuser.com.

Comment: Should we assume you are on Windows?

Comment: _netstat -ano_ on windows shows the port and the PID to find the listening process.

Comment: Tag `apache` suggests higher likelihood of being on Linux. Also note that the tag description says to use http://serverfault.com

Comment: @Andreas I think that the OP thought that Apache Tomcat needs to be tagged with apache and tomcat.

Answer (score 4):

Tomcat uses -

```
8005,8080,8009
```

Those three ports.

Open up command prompt -

```
 C:\.....>netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:8080
 TCP    0.0.0.0:8080      0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1220
 C:\....\username>taskkill /F /PID 1220
```

It will kill that task.Try it.

Answer (score 2):

METHOD 1

ps -aef | grep java | grep apache | awk '8005'

list of process running with this port will display with its process id.

pick the process id say 1090.

kill -9 1090

METHOD 2

This will kill all the process with tomcat 
kill $(ps -aef | grep java | grep apache | awk '{print $2}')